# Why is "No" as raw_input in the following python code returning TRUE?

Tags: python, boolean

I cannot for the life of me understand why I can't get to the "else" statement no matter what I type. Any insight would be much appreciated. Am I not allowed to use more than one "or"?

```
print "Do you want to go down the tunnel? "

tunnel = raw_input ("> ")

if tunnel == "Y" or "Yes" or "Yea" or "Si" or "go" or "Aye" or "Sure":
    print "You found the gold."
else:
    print "Wrong answer, you should have gone down the tunnel. There was gold down there."
```

Comment: Alternative: `Valid = ["Y","Yes","Yea","Si","go","Aye","Sure"] if tunnel in Valid: print "You found the gold." else: print "Wrong answer, you should have gone down the tunnel."`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because in python

```
if tunnel == "Y" or "Yes" or "Yea" or "Si" or "go" or "Aye" or "Sure":
```

is equivalent to

```
if (tunnel == "Y") or ("Yes") or ("Yea") or ("Si") or ("go") or ("Aye") or ("Sure"):
```

and a nonempty string is true.

You should change your code to

```
if tunnel in ("Y", "Yes", "Yea", "Si", "go", "Aye", "Sure"):
```

or, to accept variations in capitalization:

```
if tunnel.lower() in ("y", "yes", "yea", "si", "go", "aye", "sure"):
```

or maybe even use a regex.

In Python 2.7 and more, you can even use sets, which are fasters than tuples when using `in`.

```
if tunnel.lower() in {"y", "yes", "yea", "si", "go", "aye", "sure"}:
```

But you really will get the perf boost from python 3.2 and above, since before the implementation of sets litterals is not as optimised as tuples ones.

Comment: Or perhaps `if tunnel.lower() in ('y', ...)`

Comment: Or, if not using Python syntax, but classical syntax, you'd have `if tunnel == "Y" or tunnel == "Yes" or tunnel == "Yea"` and so on.

Comment: `if tunnel.capitalize() in ("Y", ...)` and `if tunnel.upper() in ('Y', ...)` would work as well, so long as the formatting is consistent.

Comment: or if you don't want to write multiple quoted strings in a tuple, you could try `if tunnel.lower() in "y yes yea si go aye sure".split():`

Comment: I Would probably even make a tuple and add a name to it like `affirmative = ("y", "yes", "yea", "si", "go", "aye", "sure")` and then check it like `if tunnel.lower() in affirmative`. But that is basicly the same answer that is already given.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and very helpful response. I'm just starting out and that was the first question I have ever posted to stack overflow (or any coding forum for that matter), and I've got to say: I'm thoroughly impressed! Hopefully as I learn more, I'll be able to help contribute more to the community.

Comment: @Shawabawa: Sorry, the checkmark is pretty slick UI, but for a noob it wasn't immediately apparent how to accept the answer. OOPS! :)

Answer (score -1):

Like the answer above says, when you cast a `str` type to a `bool` only the empty string returns false:

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool("No")
True
>>>
```

So, when you say:

```
if (tunnel == 'y') or 'foobar':
   print('woo')
```

that statement will be evaluated to:

```
if (tunnel == 'y') or True:
   print('woo')
```

The moral of the story is that it's  good idea to have an interpreter running while you're editing code then you can try out small chunks of complex expressions before you put them together :)